# How do I get Dialogflow's Callback URL to connect it to Gupshup?

Tags: url, callback, dialogflow-es, gupshup

I'm new to these types of web programming issues. The thing is, I have a functioning Dialogflow bot that I want to connect to Gupshup. My Gupshup App (not live yet) has a field to Link my Bot with the Callback URL.

What is that? How do I get/obtain it? The bot is linked to a Google Cloud Function, so I thought i took the url of that function, but that didn't work.
[image: Link my Bot]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We are planning to introduce a new way to integrate with dialogflow in few weeks. Just wait for it.

Comment: Oh, do you work in Gupshup? Is there any docs I can read already? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have to get it done now, so I'd like to know where to get the callback url. Do I have to have my own server in where I "host" the bot and set up the htttp requests that Gupshup needs?

Comment: 1. I work at Gupshup
2. Do you have a spare setup where you can create a bot and accept the request? Then you can start a server over there and accept the calls from Gupshup and forward to Dialogflow if needed. But currently, Dialogflow URL cannot be added directly for a bot.

Comment: @MauroOyhanart We've added Dialogflow support in Gupshup. Please try it out and let me know.. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will make another Stackoverflow post with questions on this matter.

Comment: I hope its ready by now, if yes please share the details.

Comment: There is a new bot type for dialogflow. You can now directly use that @JohnJoseph